# Using mutate() and the srvyr package for the calculation of percentages in a survey with weights - why does R return an error?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I recently started working with r and srvyr. I am currently struggling with the following problem:

I would like to calculate percentages in a weighted survey for some groups. My variable of interest here is "call". My data frame (df)looks looks a bit like this:

```
df <- read.table(text=" 
          educ     call     wealth     x     y      z 
A           1        0          1       20    12   0.9
B           3        0          2       21    13   0.8
C           5        1          3       22    14   1.1
D           2        0          2       23    12   0.8 
E           1        1          1       24    16   0.92", header=T)`
 library(srvyr)

 survey_design <- df %>% 
              as_survey_design(ids = x, strata = y, weights = z)

 syv2 <- survey_design %>% 
 group_by(educ) %>%
 mutate(call_rate = n / sum(n)) %>%
 filter(call == 1) %>%
 select(educ, call_rate)
```

When I try this code, I get the following error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.

However, without using srvyr, I do not get this error.

I have tried the code for several variables.

**1** Basically, I am looking for the easiest way to calculate the percentages of subgroups across columns/variables in srvyr. Most of my variables are binary.

**2** Is there an elegant way to perform this operation for multiple variables. I would like to use the variable `call` all the time, but look at different subgroups in other variables (`educ` is only one example here)?

**3** Is it possible to combine the srvyr package with TableOne to calculate absolute numbers / percentages and confidence intervals of 95%?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I did. I get the following error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator. @symbolrush

Comment: That's probably due to numerical variables represented as characters, see my edit.

Comment: I checked the variables. They are all classified as integer. @symbolrush. That should normally work, right?

Comment: I tried with `as.numeric` on each column. It still returns the same error.

Comment: Do you have any further thoughts? @symbolrush

Answer (score 3, accepted):

author of srvyr here (found this via a vanity search). @symbolrush 's answer may avoid the error, but to calculate proportions like this and take the survey weights into consideration you'll want to use the `summarize()` function instead of `mutate()` + `filter()`

I believe what you really want is:

```r
df <- read.table(text="         educ     call     wealth     x     y      z 
A           1        0          1       20    12   0.9
B           3        0          2       21    13   0.8
C           5        1          3       22    14   1.1
D           2        0          2       23    12   0.8 
E           1        1          1       24    16   0.92", header=T)
library(srvyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'srvyr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter

# required because your example dataset's weights aren't structured like real data
options(survey.lonely.psu="remove") 


survey_design <- df %>% 
  as_survey_design(ids = x, strata = y, weights = z)

syv2 <- survey_design %>% 
  group_by(educ) %>%
  summarize(call = survey_mean(call))

syv2
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>    educ  call call_se
#>   <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1 0.505   0.250
#> 2     2 0       0    
#> 3     3 0       0    
#> 4     5 1       0

# Need to use something like purrr::map (or lapply) to iterate over different grouping variables
library(purrr)
syv3 <- map_dfr(c("educ", "wealth"), function(grp_var) {
  survey_design %>% 
    group_by_at(grp_var) %>% 
    summarize(result = survey_mean(call)) %>% 
    rename(group_level = !!grp_var) %>% 
    mutate(group_var = grp_var) %>%
    select(group_var, group_level, result, result_se)
})
syv3
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#>   group_var group_level result result_se
#>   <chr>           <int>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 educ                1  0.505     0.250
#> 2 educ                2  0         0    
#> 3 educ                3  0         0    
#> 4 educ                5  1         0    
#> 5 wealth              1  0.505     0.250
#> 6 wealth              2  0         0    
#> 7 wealth              3  1         0

# This is almost a case where you could use  dplyr's scoped functions to
# perform mean on a lot of vars, but only works if you're iterating over
# the variable you're calculating a mean on.
syv4 <- survey_design %>% 
  group_by(educ) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(call, wealth), ~survey_mean(.))

syv4
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>    educ  call call_se wealth wealth_se
#>   <int> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 0.505   0.250      1         0
#> 2     2 0       0          2         0
#> 3     3 0       0          2         0
#> 4     5 1       0          3         0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

### Update

> @ GregF: Is it possible to use the code under syv3 and get these results while splitting the results columns in (a) total = male+female, (b) female & (c) male? – msgh

Switching data sources to one included with the survey package (because the example data was running out of variables). Variables that replace ones from the old example:

- stype & sch.wide -> educ & wealth
- api99            -> call
- yr.rnd           -> sex

```r
library(srvyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'srvyr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(purrr)
data(api, package = "survey")

dstrata <- apistrat %>%
  as_survey(strata = stype, weights = pw)

syv5 <- map_dfr(c("stype", "sch.wide"), function(grp_var) {
  dstrata %>% 
    group_by_at(c(grp_var)) %>% 
    summarize(
      result_yr = survey_mean(ifelse(yr.rnd == "Yes", api99, NA), na.rm = TRUE),
      result_nonyr = survey_mean(ifelse(yr.rnd == "No", api99, NA), na.rm = TRUE),                      
      result = survey_mean(api99)
    ) %>% 
    rename(group_level = !!grp_var) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
    mutate(group_var = grp_var) %>%
    select(group_var, group_level, dplyr::starts_with("result"))
})

syv5
#> # A tibble: 5 x 8
#>   group_var group_level result_yr result_yr_se result_nonyr result_nonyr_se
#>   <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1 stype     E                528.         22.7         660.            14.2
#> 2 stype     H                484           0           620.            15.9
#> 3 stype     M                506.         49.6         615.            17.0
#> 4 sch.wide  No               426.         17.8         611.            18.5
#> 5 sch.wide  Yes              536.         22.2         654.            12.0
#> # ... with 2 more variables: result <dbl>, result_se <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

**Update 2**: Is it possible to combine TableOne + the srvyr package to get absolute numbers, percentages and confidence intervals? I realised that this would have been much easier.

Comment: thank you for this. This is incredibly helpful! @GregF

Comment: @ GregF: Is it possible to use the code under syv3 and get these results while splitting the results columns in (a) total = male+female, (b) female & (c) male?

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: @msgh - re: your update 2 - I do not think it's possible to specify weights in the TableOne package, and srvyr does not currently add methods for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `mutate(call_rate = n() / sum(n())` and be sure all you're variables are represented numerical. You may coerce character variables containing numbers to a numerical representation using `as.numeric` on each column.

---

**TL;DR:**

Since `n` is a function, calling `n` inside your code returns a `closure` (roughly this means it returns the source of the function) instead of actually calling that function.

Look at the following minimal example:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% mutate(freq = n / sum(n))
```

this returns an error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: invalid
>   'type' (closure) of argument.

whereas

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% mutate(freq = n() / sum(n()))
```

actually executes.

Or simply type `dplyr::n` in the console and you see that function body:

```
function () 
{
    abort("This function should not be called directly")
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```